# How to improve performance of a nested loop operation which queries a postgres database and compares RegEx

Tags: regex, database, postgresql, algorithm

I am facing some time performance issue. My scenario is the following:

I have a database table `Product` which stores products of different vendors in a table.

```
Product
+------------------+-------------------+
| Name             | Vendor            |
+==================+===================+
| iPhone_12        | apple             |
+------------------+-------------------+
| iPhone_11        | apple             |
+------------------+-------------------+
| Samsung Galaxy   | samsung           |
+------------------+-------------------+
```

I also have a table `Subscription` where my customers can "subscribe" to products that they own. I allow my customers to use **RegEx** for subscriptions so the `Subscription` table might look like this:

```
Subscription
+----+------------------+-------------------+-------------+
| Id | Name             | Vendor            | CustomerId  |
+====+==================+===================+=============+
| 0  | iPhone_*         | apple             | 1           |
+----+------------------+-------------------+-------------+
| 1  | iPad_*           | app*              | 2           |
+----+------------------+-------------------+-------------+
```

Now I have a website where my customer can view all his subscribed products.

1. For instance `subscription[Id=0]` would match **any** iPhone_* (iPhone_12, iPhone_11 in this case) from the product table.
2. For `subscription[Id=1]` it will match **any** iPad_* from **any** vendor that starts with `app` from the product table.

**The issue:**
In my case I have customers which have 500+ suscriptions and my products table contains +500k products. Currently I am querying all subscriptions, then iterating over all of them and for each I will query all products and do a string RegEx comparison. Here a sample example, it's not the actual code as I made this code example up but it represents how I am doing it in fact:

```
const subscribedProducts = []
for (const subscription : db.findSubscriptionsByCustomerId(1)) {
   for (const product : db.findProducts()) {
      RegEx r1 = RegEx.parse(subscription.name)
      RegEx r2 = RegEx.parse(subscription.vendor)

      if (r1.match(product.name)) && r2.match(product.vendor)) {
         subscribedProducts.push(subscription)
      }
   }
}
```

This makes the whole system VERY slow. I know there are `Patterns` for SQL queries but they are not as advanced as RegEx.

Does someone have an idea how I could improve that? Code-wise or database-wise or in any other way? This is very important for me.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Postgresql supports POSIX Regular Expressions, why not do filtering in select query
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-REGEXP

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for can be accomplished in a single query. The first thing is to convert `name` and `vendor` columns from `subscription` table to valid regular expressions. Those columns do not a regular expression, they contain a wild carded value. Once converted you just Join with the `product` table.  ( see [demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=c20f927903f3b827fcffe87b34d434cf) )

```
with sub_as_regex( id, name, vendor, customerid, name_rx, ven_rx) as
      ( select id, name, vendor, customerid 
             ,  case when position ( '*' in name) > 0 
                    then concat( '^', substring(name,1,position ( '*' in name) - 1) )
                    else concat( '^', name, '$') 
               end 
             , case when position ( '*' in vendor) > 0 
                    then concat( '^', substring(vendor,1,position ( '*' in vendor) - 1) ) 
                    else concat( '^', vendor, '$') 
               end
          from subscription
       ) --select *  from sub_as_regex
select sr.id         "Subscription Id"
     , sr.customerid "Customer Id"
     , p.name        "Product Name" 
  from product  p 
  join sub_as_regex sr  
    on (    p.name   ~* sr.name_rx 
        and p.vendor ~* sr.ven_rx
       );
```

The `sub_as_regex` CTE essentially adds two columns to the `subscription` table that contain the actual regular expression needed for name and vendor columns. The main select then joins the CTE to the with the `product` table with case insensitive regexp match.  
As an improvement you could add  those columns to the actual table and *calculate* them during insert and update DML with before Insert/Update triggers. In that case you need only the main query.

```
    select sr.id         "Subscription Id"
         , sr.customerid "Customer Id"
         , p.name        "Product Name" 
      from product  p 
      join sub_as_regex sr  
        on (    p.name   ~* sr.name_rx 
            and p.vendor ~* sr.ven_rx
           );
```

Comment: That's already a great step into the right direction I think. You're right, it's not directly a regex but just a wildcard. Only issue with this is that your approach won't work if the customer subscribes to something like `iPhone_*_Pro`. Do you know how these cases could be handled?

Comment: I believe the strategy converting subscriptions columns into a regexp is still valid, but maybe a tactical adjustment. I do not have time at the moment to validate, perhaps the next couple days. Convert the wild card specification (*) into the equivalent regular expression string (\.*). For example change the `case ... name` to a simple [replace function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html) `replace(subscription.name,'*','\.*')` and `replace(subscription.vendor,'*','\.*')`. You may need to play around with the anchors, (`^` and `$`).